# Speech To Text enhancement

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition, development-environment, language-enhancement

This question might sound dummy for you guys, i'm just copy pasting my pain from my end users to you.

I have developed an app for a company which will let users perform search for certain items in a database.

The app allows for speaking as an input method, using the default input method in the default keyboard.

This is actually something that we do not control, which means users can simply choose which input method to use to type the search query (hand written on screen, keyboard, voice...) and this is a standard in any app like messaging, Whats app ...etc.

The Problem is that users are not satisfied with the output of the speech recognition, which gives so many errors specially when users have a bad accent or there is a noise around...

Is there a way to enhance the output of the speech recognition

Regards,
Tariq

Answer (score 1):

try to check and follow this https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/  tutorial